# Android Screen Type Targetting for 7"+ Devices

Tags: android

I am about to publish an app to the Google Android Marketplace and would like to ensure it only appears for devices with a screen size of 7"+ (600px x 1024px as a minimum); in specific for the Kindle Fire / Galaxy Tab 7"/10.1". I understand from the Android Developer Site that the way to do this is by way of using the `<supports-screens>` [tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

Would the following accomplish what I am looking to do:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

Is this best practice or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't say it's bad practice, but you are limiting your audience.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA Completely agree; this is actually a port of an iPad app and requires the larger screen size.

Comment: As it is also recommended on the [<compatible-screen>](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) description to use the <support-screens> tag to support only larger Screens, I would say yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this, I would leave only xlarge screens. As you can see at the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page, large screens are roughly from 4" to 7", which is not what you've described.

By the way, resolution and screen size **are not the same**. Screen size refers to the physical size of the screen, and a large screen can still have quite different resolutions depending on the pixel density. For example, 1024x600 you mentioned can be qualified as xlarge, large, or even normal depending on the pixel density.

Some other remarks: I wouldn't use `anyDensity` because it is `true` by default and also wouldn't use `resizable` because it is deprecated.

Comment: Would leaving only xlarge screens make it available to the Kindle Fire and Galaxy Tab 7"?

Comment: @dSquared If you're going for the specific devices that balance on the edge of the two screen types, then it is safer to use both large and xlarge. However, you will include devices with screens which are far smaller than 7" by doing this.